# Removing TAGS in a document

Tags: python, regex

I need to find all the tags in .txt format (SEC filing) and remove from the filing.

Well, as a beginner of Python, I used the following code to find the tags, but it returns None, None, ... and I don't know how to remove all the tags. My question is how to find all the tags <....> and remove all the tags so that the document contains everything but tags.

```
import re
tags = [re.search(r'<.+>', line) for line in mylist]
#mylist is the filename opened by open(filename, 'rU').readlines()
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', line)
```

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) and `<.*?>` expression

Comment: I don't know much about regexes, but what's the point of `re.MULTILINE` here?  There aren't any `^` or `$` markers.  Do you mean `re.DOTALL`, to allow for newlines within a tag?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
re.sub(r'<[^>]+>', '', open(filename, 'r').read())
```

Your current code is getting a `None` for each line that does not include angle-bracketed tags.

You probably want to use `[^>]` to make sure it matches only up to the first >.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you're going to need a different regex.   The one you have will select everything between the first '<' and the last '>' So the string:

```
I can type in <b>BOLD</b>
```

would render the match:

**BOLD**

The way to fix this would be to use a lazy operators [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) has a good explanation on why you should be using

<.+?>

to match HTML tags.  And ultimately, you should be substituting, so:

re.sub(r'', '', line)

Though, I suspect what you'd actually like to match is between the tags.  Here's where a good lookahead can do wonders!

(?<=>).+?(?=<)

Looks crazy, but it breaks down pretty easy.  Let's start with what you know:

```
.+?
```

matches a string of arbitrary length.  ? means it will match the shortest string possible. (The laziness we added before)

```
(<?=...)
```

is a lookbehind.  It literally looks behind itself without capturing the expression.

```
(?=...)
```

is a lookahead.  It's the same as a lookbehind.  Then with a little findall:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=>).+?(?=<)', line);
```

Now, you can iterate over the array and trim an unnecessary spaces that got left behind and make for some really nice output!  Or, if you'd really like to use a substitution method (I know I would):

```
re.sub(r'\s*(?:</+?>\s*)+', ' ', line)
```

the

```
\s*
```

will match any amount of whitespace attached to a tag, which you can then replace with one space, whittlling down those unnerving double and triple spaces that often result from over careful tagging.  As a bonus, the

```
(?: ... )
```

is known as a non-capturing group (it won't give you smaller sub matches in your result).  It's not really necessary in this situation for your purposes, but groups are always useful things to think about, and it's good practice to only capture the ones you need.  Tacking a + onto the end of that (as I did), will capture as many tags as are right next to each other, eliminating them into a single space.  So if the file has

```
This is <b> <i> overemphasized </b> </i>!
```

you'd get

```
This is overemphasized !
```

instead of

```
This is   overemphasized  !
```